# Suggestion for a better WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a below query:

```
SELECT AppInitiatedDate,
       Incomplete.Product1,
       Incomplete.Product2, 
       Incomplete.Product3, 
       Incomplete.Product4, 
       Incomplete.Product5, 
       CASE WHEN 
         len(Incomplete.Product1) > 0 or
         len(Incomplete.Product2) > 0 or
         len(Incomplete.Product3) > 0 or
         len(Incomplete.Product4) > 0 or
         len(Incomplete.Product5) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
       END AS NumberIncomplete,
       CASE WHEN AppInitiatedDate >= @StartDate AND AppInitiatedDate < @EndDate 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END AS NumberInitiated
FROM [TableNames]
WHERE AppInitiatedDate >= @StartDate) 
  AND AppInitiatedDate < @EndDate) 
  AND  **(DecisionStatus.Status in ('Active', 'Inactive', 'Complete'
         , 'Cancelled', 'WithDrawn', 'CounterOffer') 
   OR (DecisionStatus.Status = 'Cancelled' 
       AND DecisionStatus.Status IS NOT NULL)** 
--DecisionStatus table inclues fields like 
--Active, Inactive, Complete, Cancelled, WithDrawn, CounterOffer etc. ALso
```

The Scenario is: I want all the records of Incomplete Product Application with the all Status included in DecisionStatus table but don't want Cancelled records where all the records are null. Please suggest if I can imporve the above query.

Comment: Side note but should really all conditions in the case be on the same product? :)

Comment: Changing in (active, etc) to status <> Cancelled might be an improvement.  It depends on how you want to treat new types of statuses that might come up in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I get your point correctly, but try this

`WHERE AppInitiatedDate >= @StartDate)` 
   `AND AppInitiatedDate < @EndDate)` 
   `AND IsNull(DecisionStatus.Status,'Cancelled') <> 'Cancelled'`

Comment: Thank You so much....This is exactly what I was looking for. :) just a better condition...

Comment: I am glad it helped, For boosting performance create a non clustered index on `Status` field